# How to unzip multiple zip folders using VBscript?

Tags: vbscript, unzip

I need a VB script to unzip multiple different zip folders. I have this script - but it does not work.

```
Sub Unzip()  
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
For Each f In fso.GetFolder("C:\Dal\").Files
  If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(f)) = "zip" Then
    Unzip f.path, "C:\Dal"
  End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: vb.net is not vbscript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NameSpace` method doesn't support wildcards. Try something like this:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
For Each f In fso.GetFolder("C:\").Files
  If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(f)) = "zip" And Left(f.Name, 11) = "DailySearch" Then
    Unzip f.Path, "C:\DailySearch"
  End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks @Ansgar! I tried using this and I get an error: Line 3 Char 7 Expected '='

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It should've been `For Each f In ...`, not `For f In ...`. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks again @Ansgar - it fixed the first error but I get one more - line 5 Char 5 Type mismatch: 'Unzip'

Comment: My code snippet doesn't run by itself. You still need the procedure from your question.

Comment: Hi @Ansgar - I am sorry I  missed it before. I fixed it and I get no errors when I run it - But the files are not getting unzipped. Nothing happens.

Comment: @user2871996 Works just fine for me. Please update your question with your modified code.

Comment: @user2871996 I didn't say to replace the code inside your procedure with my code. *Keep* the `Unzip` procedure you had and *add* my code *outside* of that procedure.

Comment: I am so sorry - I am just learning VB and I did not get it. I tried that and works perfectly. Thank you!!!!!!